# Is it possible to write a Just In Time (JIT) compiler for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, jit

I'm interested in learning more about how Haskell compiles down to native code. I understand that Haskell is statically typechecked, which is why you might not want to do this. But is it possible?

Comment: why would static typechecking prevent one from writing a JIT? In fact, it's easier to JIT a statically-typed language than a dynamically-typed one.

Comment: A JIT compiler is just a regular compiler that you run a lot :) .

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Hmm, the whole point of a statically typechecked language is that it is typechecked at compile time, right? From what I understand, a JIT compiler would compile source language to native code at run-time. But wouldn't this defeat the point of static type checking? Perhaps I'm missing something fundamental.

Comment: Note that I'm talking about the case where I'm compiling .hs to native code, and not .hs -> bytecode/some IR. In the latter case, I understand how the benefits of static type checking would come into play.

Comment: you are talking about the compiler telling the programmer her mistakes? Yes that's a bit defeated - but still the JIT could reject programs still faster than running them

Comment: Possible? Sure. You can do the same with C or C++ too...The advantage of JIT is that when compiling it can make use of some runtime information such as: which pieces of code are run more often, how the flow of the code goes on average, which data is being used and its average size/lifetime etc.  This helps in performing optimizations. JITs are a thing for dynamically typed languages because you can exploit runtime type information, but if you already have that a priori you simply have one less thing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thesis about compiling a lazy functional language JIT might interest you: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3265448/schilling.thesis.final.2014-01-20.pdf

Another two resources that might help on your quest:

http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~pbv/aulas/linguagens/peytonjones92implementing.pdf

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/pj-lester-book/